# django add_to_class() making models inheritance/MRO work wrong

Tags: django, inheritance, method-resolution-order

I have a problem with inheritance on my models when adding fields via add_to_class(). 
I have a models `File(models.Model)` and `Image(File)` - these come from django-filer.

In my app I'm importing them and adding fields and methods:

```
def method_x(self):
    print "x"

File.add_to_class("expiration_date", models.DateField(null=True, blank=True))
File.add_to_class("method_x", method_x)
```

Image should inherit both of those but it gets only the method(s), not field(s):

```
>>> some_file = File.objects.get(id=8)
>>> some_image = Image.objects.get(id=8)
>>>
>>> print some_file.expiration_date # this works
... None
>>>
>>> some_image.metgod_x() # this works
>>> x
>>>
>>> print some_image.expiration_date # and this not
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'expiration_date'
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your model's `add_to_class` does not add the field as an attribute. it just calls `contribute_to_class` on your field: 
[`django/db/models/base.py#L218`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/722d4068a7e798f65b01d0d60676f7e8eff8703b/django/db/models/base.py#L218)

Your field's `contribute_to_class` does not do it either. It just adds the field to the model's `_meta` member: [`django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L234`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/722d4068a7e798f65b01d0d60676f7e8eff8703b/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L234)

Comment: +1 I updated the links so they point to Github directly at a fixed point in time rather then tracking the latest code. The links reference Django 1.3.1.